# Trying to pass array parameters to create dynamic URLs

Tags: javascript, variables, url, dynamic-url

I am trying to add a column to my table that has an icon to mouseover in it and shows a preview thumbnail of the record page it links to.

So far i got the visual of the thumbnail at mouseover and also the additional fields. Unfortunately i can only make it work with a static URL.
As soon as i try to add a variable to the URL my whole table is not displayed anymore.

This is the code right now, which has the static URL.

```
function makeArray(arr) {
var array = [];
for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
    var row = { date:'', view:'', name:'', comment:'', createdAt:'', updatedAt:'',reportId:''};

    row.date = new Date(arr[i].date).toLocaleDateString();
    row.view = '<a class="tiptext">view<iframe class="description" src="http://myurl.com/report.html?62"></iframe></a>';
    row.name = arr[i].name;
    row.comment = arr[i].comment;
    row.createdAt = arr[i][36];
    row.updatedAt = arr[i].updatedAt;
    row.reportId = arr[i].reportId;
    array.push(row);
}
showDataTable(array);
```

what i want to do is instead of having it link to (in this case) record 62, to use the reportId of each record and insert it into the URL instead of the 62.

I tried to find a solution for quite a bit now, but i just can't seem to find it.
Do you guys have any idea how to solve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

please try this one:

```
 row.view = `<a class="tiptext">view<iframe class="description" src="myurl.com/report.html?${arr[i].reportId}"></iframe></a>`;
```

Comment: now it shows me the page preview but without any values... any ideas on how i can solve this? i guess it doesn't call the necessary functions

Comment: it seems like it shows
    http://myurl.com/report.html?
so it doesn't pass any value

Comment: In case it show only "myurl.com/report.html?" it might possible that row.reportId does not contain any value. Can you debug that row.reportId has a value for every row?

Comment: it does have a value, if i display 
    row.reportId = arr[i].reportId;
it shows me the correct IDs for each row, it just seems to be a problem to pass it into that URL

Comment: please replace row.reportId with arr[i].reportId in the above line.

like this one:


row.view = `<a class="tiptext">view<iframe class="description" src="myurl.com/report.html?${arr[i].reportId}"></iframe></a>`;

Comment: no it didn't work! it still shows a blank preview...
I also tried to put ' before and after the variable but that stops my whole table from working...

Comment: alright, it did work my friend! thank you very much
I was using ' instead of `
this made it work, I was not expecting this to be that important! thank you

Comment: great! you are welcome! If its helpful please accept the answer.